# HTML5 video streaming - download

Tags: html, video, streaming

I read that the HTML5 video tag can't stream video...

By streaming i mean the possibility to download a video only from the middle of it and not from the beginning.

Apparently you can set the *currentTime* to the middle but in the background it will download all the movie.

On the other hand YouTube's HTML5 player seems to stream just fine.

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks...

Comment: this will depend on your server... if the server supports ByteRangeRequests then the <video> element can be smarter about what it requests

Comment: My server upports ByteRange. Still, no real streaming...